# Creating Views - iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview

Im making a simple application to learn getsure recognizers.. I have created four views in my window but when i load the application, the size is completely different to how i had arranged them before.. any ideas why or how i can fix this?

i am importing some co-ordinates in my .h file for pinching.. could this be why?

thanks

Comment: how did you create your views?   In code or in Interface Builder?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are setting the views' frames correctly. For example, if you want your view to be 100 pixels wide, 50 pixels tall, and be in the top-left corner of the window, you'd write the following:

```
myView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50);
```

If you wanted to push that view over 10 pixels to the right and 15 pixels down (but with the same dimensions), you'd write the following instead:

```
myView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 15, 100, 50);
```

For more information on view frames, read through all the attributes in the "Configuring the Bounds and Frame Rectangles" section on Apple's [UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html).